# How is it possible for mod_wsgi to be compiled against Python 2.7.3 but use the 2.7.2 runtime?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django

The following is what appears in my error_log:

```
[Sat Nov 17 23:13:14 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.3.
[Sat Nov 17 23:13:14 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.2.
```

If I check my $PATH variable and even in /etc/paths, /usr/local/bin (which contains Python 2.7.3) comes before /usr/bin (which contains Python 2.7.2).

Is there some other path that I'm missing out on?  How can I get the correct runtime to be used?

Comment: Just as a clarification this is on Mac OS X 10.8 running the pre-installed version of Apache 2.

Comment: I see you've already solved it - but as information, your own $PATH will not affect a service started from launchd or using a script that sets its own path or that is started with e.g. sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine the reason why the older runtime was used.

The quick fix was to symlink /usr/bin/python (which was originally 2.7.2) to /usr/local/bin/python where the newer version of Python is making /usr/bin/python also 2.7.3.  Upon restarting Apache, 2.7.3 was used meaning somehow /usr was being used over /usr/local.  However, I didn't want to stick with this as the solution, so I removed the symlink.

After some further digging, I looked at the apachectl script and was able to determine that it was loading environment variables for Apache from /usr/sbin/envvars

I modified the following line of the envvars file to include /usr/local/lib and restarted Apache.  It loaded with Python 2.7.3 (thus solving a separate issue with _uname I was having with Django that is caused by 2.7.2/2.7.3 discrepancies)

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Comment: More likely should be rebuilding mod_wsgi from fresh source code and use the --disable-framework to configure. Still don't know why for some people the linker doesn't link in reference to correct framework, but using that configure option usually helps.